# passing and accepting same types, still getting incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to long

Tags: java

I have gone through other posts on the same topic, but doesn't seems to be fixing my error. In my main class I have a variable which is declared as double.

```
double R_b2 = 60000/r_b2;
```

I am passing this value to a thread:

```
Thread prodThread2 = new Thread(new Baker(cupcakes_sharedQueue, size,R_b2), "Cupcakes");
```

In the constructor, I declared it as the following

```
private final Vector prod_sharedQueue;
private final int SIZE;
private final double rate;
public Baker(Vector prod_sharedQueue, int size, double rate) {
   this.prod_sharedQueue = prod_sharedQueue;
   this.SIZE = size;
   this.rate = rate;
}
```

I am using this passed value as a timer to sleep the thread.

I am getting the following error:

> Baker.java:36: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to long
>   Thread.sleep(rate);
>   in the line:
>   Thread.sleep(rate);

What is wrong? I tried to use int, it works without errors, just that I do not get the correct value I need. Other than that I tried float,double,long all are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` is declared to take a `long`, not a `double`.  You need to manually cast it:

```
Thread.sleep((long) rate);
```

Note that this will truncate down to the nearest millisecond below.

Comment: Thank you very much. OMG I spent like 1 hour trying to fix this and you saved me in a second. Thank you very much it works now

Comment: @EbinPIssac No problem, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

A simple casting thing, because double use more bit to represent a value

Thread.sleep((long)rate)

Comment: "because double use more bit to represent a value" Both double and long are 64-bit values.

Comment: Hooo, yeah my bad, was thinking about float